# lxml not working with django, scraperwiki

Tags: django, lxml, scraperwiki

I'm working on a django app that goes through Illinois' General Assembly website to scrape some pdfs. While deployed on my desktop it works fine until urllib2 times out. When I try to deploy on my Bluehost server, the lxml part of the code throws up an error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import scraperwiki
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import lxml.etree
import re
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from legi.models import Votes

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        chmbrs =['http://www.ilga.gov/house/', 'http://www.ilga.gov/senate/']
        for chmbr in chmbrs:
            site = chmbr    
            url = urllib2.urlopen(site)
            content = url.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
            links = []
            linkStats = []
            x=0
            y=0
            table = soup.find('table', cellpadding=3)
            for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
                if re.findall('Bills', a['href']):
                    l = (site + a['href']+'&Primary=True')
                    links.append(str(l))
                    x+=1
                    print x
            for link in links:
                url = urllib2.urlopen(link)
                content = url.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
                table = soup.find('table', cellpadding=3)
                for a in table.findAll('a',href=True):
                    if re.findall('BillStatus', a['href']):
                        linkStats.append(str('http://ilga.gov'+a['href']))
            for linkStat in linkStats:
                url = urllib2.urlopen(linkStat)
                content = url.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
                for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
                    if re.findall('votehistory', a['href']):
                        vl = 'http://ilga.gov/legislation/'+a['href']
                        url = urllib2.urlopen(vl)
                        content = url.read()
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
                        for b in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
                            if re.findall('votehistory', b['href']):
                                llink = 'http://ilga.gov'+b['href']
                                try:
                                    u = urllib2.urlopen(llink)
                                    x = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(u.read())
                                    root = lxml.etree.fromstring(x)
                                    pages = list(root)
                                    chamber = str()
                                    for page in pages:
                                        print "working_1"
                                        for el in page:
                                            print "working_2"
                                            if el.tag == 'text':
                                                if int(el.attrib['top']) == 168:
                                                    chamber = el.text
                                                if re.findall("Senate Vote", chamber):
                                                    if int(el.attrib['top']) >= 203 and int(el.attrib['top']) < 231:
                                                        title = el.text
                                                        if (re.findall('House', title)):
                                                            title = (re.findall('[0-9]+', title))
                                                            title = "HB"+title[0]
                                                        elif (re.findall('Senate', title)):
                                                            title = (re.findall('[0-9]+', title))
                                                            title = "SB"+title[0]
                                                    if int(el.attrib['top']) >350 and int(el.attrib['top']) <650:
                                                        r = el.text
                                                        names = re.findall(r'[A-z-\u00F1]{3,}',r)
                                                        vs = re.findall(r'[A-Z]{1,2}\s',r)
                                                        for name in names:
                                                            legi = name
                                                            for vote in vs:
                                                                v = vote
                                                            if Votes.objects.filter(legislation=title).exists() == False:
                                                                c = Votes(legislation=title, legislator=legi, vote=v)
                                                                c.save()    
                                                                print 'saved'
                                                            else:
                                                                print 'not saved'                                                       
                                                elif int(el.attrib['top']) == 189:
                                                    chamber = el.text
                                                if re.findall("HOUSE ROLL CALL", chamber):
                                                    if int(el.attrib['top']) > 200 and int(el.attrib['top']) <215:
                                                        title = el.text
                                                        if (re.findall('HOUSE', title)):
                                                            title = (re.findall('[0-9]+', title))
                                                            title = "HB"+title[0]
                                                        elif (re.findall('SENATE', title)):
                                                            title = (re.findall('[0-9]+', title))
                                                            title = "SB"+title[0]
                                                    if int(el.attrib['top']) >385 and int(el.attrib['top']) <1000:
                                                        r = el.text
                                                        names = re.findall(r'[A-z-\u00F1]{3,}',r)
                                                        votes = re.findall(r'[A-Z]{1,2}\s',r)
                                                        for name in names:
                                                            legi = name
                                                            for vote in votes:
                                                                v = vote
                                                            if Votes.objects.filter(legislation=title).exists() == False:
                                                                c = Votes(legislation=title, legislator=legi, vote=v)
                                                                c.save()
                                                                print 'saved'
                                                            else:
                                                                print 'not saved'

                                except:
                                    pass
```

**EDIT 1**
Here's the error trace

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home7/maythirt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home7/maythirt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home7/maythirt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home7/maythirt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home7/maythirt/GAB/legi/management/commands/vote.py", line 51, in handle
    root = lxml.etree.fromstring(x)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3032, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:68121)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1786, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102470)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1674, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101299)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1074, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96481)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91290)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92476)
  File "parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91939)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: None
```

Comment: Difficult to say anything without the error trace.

Comment: Sorry about that! Added it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jonathan mentioned, it may be the output of `scraperwiki.pdftoxml()` that's causing a problem. You could display or log the value of `x` to confirm it.

Specifically, [`pdftoxml()`](https://github.com/scraperwiki/scraperwiki-python/blob/master/scraperwiki/utils.py#L38-L54) runs an external program `pdftohtml` and uses temporary files to store the PDF and XML.

What I'd also check for is:

1. Is `pdftohtml` correctly set up **on your server**?
2. If so, does the conversion to XML work if you directly run it in a shell on the server with the PDF that the code's failing on? The command it's executing is `pdftohtml -xml -nodrm -zoom 1.5 -enc UTF-8 -noframes "input.pdf" "output.xml"`

If there's an issue when you directly run the command, then that's there your issue lies. With the way `pdftohtml` runs in the `scraperwiki` code, there's no easy way you'd be able to tell if the command fails.

Comment: You are right Steven. Unfortunately I'm on a shared host, not a VPS, so I can''t use yum to install the needed packages.

Answer (score 0):

They way I would go about this is add a try: except: clause and when you get the error you simply save the xml file as well as the link down to your harddrive. That way you can inspect the xml file separately.

It might be that scraperwiki.pdftoxml makes an illegal xml file for some reason. I've had that happen to me when using another pdftoxml tool.

And please refactor your code into more functions it will become a lot easier to read and maintain :).

Another way would of course to download all of the pdfs first, and then parse them all. That way you can avoid hitting the website several times whenever you fail for some reason.