# Using scraperwiki for pdf-file on disk

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, scraperwiki

I am trying to get some data out of a pdf document using scraperwiki for pyhon. It works beautifully if I download the file using *urllib2* like so:

```
pdfdata = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
xmldata = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(pdfdata)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(xmldata)
pages = list(root)
```

But here comes the tricky part. As I would like to do this for a large number of pdf-files that I have on my disk, I would like to do away with the first line and pass the pdf file directly as an argument. However, if I try

```
pdfdata = open("filename.pdf","wb")
xmldata = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(pdfdata)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(xmldata)
```

I get the following error

```
xmldata = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(pdfdata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scraperwiki/utils.py", line 44, in pdftoxml
pdffout.write(pdfdata)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not file
```

I am guessing that this occurs because I do not open the pdf correctly?

If so, is there a way to open a pdf from disk just like *urllib2.urlopen()* does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urllib2.urlopen(...).read() does just that it reads the contents of the stream returned from the url you passed as a parameter.

While open() returns a file handler. Just as urllib2 needed to do an open() call then a read() call so does file handlers.

Change your program to use the the following lines:

```
with open("filename.pdf", "rb") as pdffile:
      pdfdata=pdffile.read()

xmldata = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(pdfdata)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(xmldata)
```

This will open your pdf then read the contents into a buffer named pdfdata. From there your call to scraperwiki.pdftoxml() will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the original problem. However, now I get a different error:  `root = lxml.html.fromstring(xmldata) ... lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: None` (Full error text is too long for a comment). I am guessing this is unrelated to my original question, still any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Code: http://pastebin.com/3LUpqQ84
Full error message: http://pastebin.com/WK74TS8B

Comment: Solved. This solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005988/lxml-not-working-with-django-scraperwiki] did the trick for some reason.